¿Hay alguna función dentro de IO u otro objeto para acceder a la extensión de un archivo en vb.net 2022?
Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Hay algún método dentro del objeto IO u otro objeto que no sea el IO con el que pueda acceder a la extensión que tiene un archivo?
Tengo este método que lo hace, pero, es llamando a Scripting.FileSystemObject ...
Public Function FileExtension(ByVal FilePath As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim FSO As Object = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Return FSO.GetExtensionName(FilePath)
End Function


Con GetExtension
 Path.GetExtension("C:\archivo.txt") ' Retorna: .txt

Ojo, que la extensión incluye el punto (.)
Lo que hace esta función es buscar el primer punto de derecha a izquierda, a menos que el punto esté al final del string. Entonces no se vaya a pensar que utiliza alguna función del sistema o algo parecido, sino que simplemente analiza el string (Path)
Esta es la función en C#, por si a alguin le intera ver lo que hace por debajo
public static ReadOnlySpan < char > GetExtension(ReadOnlySpan < char > path) {
  int length = path.Length;

  for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char ch = path[i];
    if (ch == '.') {
      if (i != length - 1)
        return path.Slice(i, length - i);
      else
        return ReadOnlySpan <char> .Empty;
    }
    if (PathInternal.IsDirectorySeparator(ch))
      break;
  }
  return ReadOnlySpan <char> .Empty;
}


Sabia que tenia que tener alguna en algún lado. Gracias por tu aporte.

Solo me a funcionado una vez, las siguientes no funcionan. No entiendo por que no me ha funcionado mas que una vez, y de momento prefiero mi código que estoy seguro de que lo hace bien. Solo me preguntaba si había otra manera de hacer lo mismo.

@PolFlórezViciana Muy raro, es una función muuuuuuuy antigua de .net como para que tenga un bug. Yo hice la prueba, usándola barias veces y funciona. Saludos

A mi solo me ha funcionado una vez y no más. La función que tengo no da problemas aunque lo saca haciendo scripting y pensé que cuando actualizaron a .net ya hace años, habrían pasado dicha función al entorno pero veo que no. Se agradece la ayuda de todos modos. ¿Sabes algún otro método? Yo se otro método que es usando una función llamada ToPositionWordRight que accede con el String hasta el punto del String desde la derecha y quitando el punto ya esta la extensión pero es una forma no de sistema de creación propia. Gracias por tu tiempo.
